# Graphical Scripting Language

Tags: graphics, script

I would like to improve on the normal sleep inducing Powerpoint presentations with a moving graphical show for my "Bits to :- I'm sorry Dave" semester. So I am looking for a 3D graphics engine with scripting.

So I could say.

```
Draw open blue rectangle at xyz, label it accumulator. 
Draw chars 10010111 at abc, label VAR1.
Move chars 10010111 at abc to xyz, label LOAD or MOV
Draw chars 01001111 at abc, label VAR2 
Sleep 1000
```

I also want to be able to display any source code as in

```
 load_persons_conditionsNewPersonsID),                                                        %retract(available_person(NewPersonsID)), %Note X8
  total_slots_per_shift(Slots),                                                       
  ensure_no_preselection_of_potential_person(NewPersonsID,Slots),                                           
  check_that_a_person_is_not_already_in_a_shift(NewPersonsID),                                              
  not(person_just_used(NewPersonsID)),                                                        
  check_that_person_is_not_hated_by_someone_already_in_a_shift(NewPersonsID),                                         check_properties(NewPersonsID),                                                          
  delete_all_non_linked_properties_for_this_person(NewPersonsID),                                           
  check_conditions(NewPersonsID),                                                         
  check_that_a_person_is_not_already_in_an_overlapping_shift(NewPersonsID),
  !,                                                          
  assert(used_a_person(b_true)),                                                          
  update_persons_accumulators(NewPersonsID),
```

Then show via a karaoki bouncing ball or text color change. Each source code line to emulate program flow.

Any ideas.

Comment: Over 30 years ago I used something similar, controlling a `turtle`, using the `logo` language on the Apple II.  You could look for modern adaptations of `logo`.

Comment: How is that 3D? You don't mention how you would use the third dimension (e.g. depth).

Comment: I also want to show a small simulated neural net with active nodes. These will be in 3D to show the feedback etc.

Comment: paradroid: Good idea will Google for modern versions of logo. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Processing](http://processing.org/) should meet your needs. It's built upon the Java language, and the "scripting" environment is really just interacting with Java objects & methods. The IDE wraps everything into a "proper" Java program when it gets run. It's free, open-source, and there are a number of good books & tutorials available.

Comment: The internet being huge means too much to find and filter. That is why this Stackoverflow type site works. There is often someone, who has used or has knowledge, of exactly what one is looking for. Thanks. This looks perfect. I didn't want to re-invent the wheel by writing it my self

Comment: Ira Greenberg's book, _Processing: Creative Coding and Computational Art_ , has some good info on 3D art. Here's a sample chapter... http://www.friendsofed.com/extras/159059617X/3D-Rendering-In-Java-Mode.pdf

Comment: @kingchris - No problem.

Answer (score 2):

> **I am looking for a 3D graphics engine with scripting.**

I suspect [Flash](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/3d_animation.html) with [ActionScript](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/3dindex.htm) provides that.